# Drop rows based on a threshold value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With elasticsearch search Indexed the data. The input file much match query is dob and last name. It has student with same dob. So that file also coming as output. Have an idea about to remove low score rows. How can I approach?

```
Filename Name      DOB         Score PageNumber
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   1
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   2
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   1
81564   Kiran   11 06 1930  3.5517883   2
81564   Kiran   11 06 1930  3.5517883   33
81564   Kiran   11 06 1930  3.5517883   12
754133  peter   11 06 1930  2.5905614   1
754133  peter   11 06 1930  2.5905614   1
```

**Desired output**

```
Filename Name      DOB         Score PageNumber
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   1
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   2
11086   Ram     11 06 1930  6.4504585   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try `.std` based filtering.

```
df = df[~((df.Score - df.Score.max()).abs() > df.Score.std())]
df

   Filename Name         DOB     Score  PageNumber
0     11086  Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
1     11086  Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           2
2     11086  Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
```

`Score.std` becomes the dynamic threshold for your data.

---

Where,

```
((df.Score - df.Score.max()).abs())

0    0.000000
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    2.898670
4    2.898670
5    2.898670
6    3.859897
7    3.859897
Name: Score, dtype: float64

df.Score.std()
1.7451830491923459

df.Score.max()
6.4504584999999999
```

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you want only rows with a score greater than `3`

```
df.query('Score > 3')

   Filename   Name         DOB     Score  PageNumber
0     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
1     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           2
2     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
3     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788           2
4     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788          33
5     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788          12
```

---

Supposing you want to filter by some multiple of standard deviation

```
df[df.Score > (df.Score.mean() - 1 * df.Score.std())]

   Filename   Name         DOB     Score  PageNumber
0     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
1     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           2
2     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
3     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788           2
4     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788          33
5     81564  Kiran  11 06 1930  3.551788          12
```

---

Or you can grab just the rows that equal the max

```
df.query('Score == @df.Score.max()')

   Filename   Name         DOB     Score  PageNumber
0     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
1     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           2
2     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
```

Or

```
df[df.Score == df.Score.max()]

   Filename   Name         DOB     Score  PageNumber
0     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
1     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           2
2     11086    Ram  11 06 1930  6.450458           1
```

Comment: I dont want to be specific range like score > 3. If suppose the input file is different means that wont workout. It should compare all and show the higest score.

Comment: @prem those are the sorts of details you should include with your question.  Thank you for editing your question.